Resampling nifti image in python with nibabel
Here is my code, the output image slices are all just a part of one slice.
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nibabel.processing import resample_to_output

from_img =  nib.load("AX_T2_TSE_2024520_20_i006.nii.gz")
from_img_resampled = resample_to_output(from_img,(1,1,1))

nib.save(from_img_resampled,"from_img_resampled2.nii.gz")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].matshow(from_data[:, :, from_data.shape[-1] // 2])
ax[1].matshow(from_img_resampled.get_fdata()[:, :, from_img_resampled.shape[-1] // 2])
plt.show()



I tried many voxel sizes but I always get the same result.

Hello, sorry, it is not really clear why you are considering result wrong. Larger voxels will decrease quality of the projection. And this is seen on your graphs. Any other considerations?

ok it will have a less quality but why every slice of the image has only a part of the same slice ? it means the new images shape is 19619615 but it does not have 15 slices , but only one and devided by 15 slice wich every one is a part of that unique slice

from_img_resampled.get_fdata() [ :, :, from_img_resampled.shape[-1] // 2 ] is a whole slice (the two colons mean all the coordinates in the first two dimensions) at the position closest to halfway down the third dimension. To get the volume you can do from_img_resampled.get_fdata() [ :, :, : ]. For displaying slices in other dimensions you can replace another of those colons by a position.
